# _bson ObjectId convert into JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, bson

I tried convert it into JSON.
_id: Object
_bsontype: "ObjectID"
id: "X±¸kÍ+I¿9À"

How to convert into JSON format?

Comment: `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: I need this _id:"58b1bf5bcba40a6a5671620c" not this _id: Object _bsontype: "ObjectID" id: "X±¸kÍ+I¿9À"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson

you need to call deserialize from BSON

```
var doc_2 = bson.deserialize(data);
JSON.stringify(doc_2);
```

reading that function https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/1.0-branch/extended-json/index.js#L48

you can expect your output to maintain the "type" for you...

```
{_id:{"$oid":"58b1bf5bcba40a6a5671620c"}}
```

If you really just want the string for the OID, you can simply overwrite the string back into the _id key

```
doc["_id"] = doc["_id"].toString()
JSON.stringify(doc);
```